# Ordenar de forma corretar query mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, order-by

Eu tenho uma query para buscar alguns valores, porem o valor não me retorna de forma correta. No exemplo abaixo vai reparar que o usuario 1 esta abaixo do usuario 2. No caso a ordem deveria ser nessa sequencia> level > kills/quantidade > exp.

Exemplo 2:

**Renato 1 lugar** (level: 105, exp: 90, kills/quantidade: 100) = o level esta 105 e kills/quantidade 100 sendo assim os demais estão inferior aos 2 principais quesitos.

**Pedro 2 lugar** (level: 105, exp: 500, kills/quantidade: 90) é o mesmo level do 1 lugar porem o primeiro lugar tem 10 kill a mais.

**Pietro 3 lugar** (level: 105, exp: 1000, kills/quantidade: 80) = esse tem o mesmo level do 1 e 2 porem tem mais exp porem tem 10 kills/quantidade a menos.

**Gustavo 4 lugar** (level: 90, exp: 700, kills/quantidade: 70) = esse tem level 90 600 exp esta em 4 lugar.

**Renan 5 lugar** (level: 80, exp: 800, kills/quantidade: 60) = esse tem level 80 tem mais exp que o 4 lugar porem tem menos kills/quantidade.

Exemplo final:

Vendo a imagem abaixo a ordem seria:

`id: 241
 id: 591
 id: 125
 id: 166
 id: 144`

```sql
SELECT player.id,player.`name`,player.`level`, player.job,player_index.empire,player.exp,IFNULL(player.quantidade,0) as kills, player.quantidade FROM player LEFT JOIN player_index ON player_index.id=player.account_id LEFT JOIN kill_system ON player.id=kill_system.id WHERE player.`name` NOT LIKE '[%]%' OR player.`name` LIKE '%[VIP]%' ORDER BY player.`level` DESC, quantidade DESC, player.playtime DESC, player.exp DESC;
```

[image: Imagem de exemplo]

Comment: Kills e quantidade são sempre 1 !? Anula o "order by" ...

Comment: Qual o tipo de dado da coluna quantidade? Está parecendo que é varchar, se realmente for isso, a ordenação realmente vai ficar errada, precisa ser de um tipo numérico para reproduzir o resultado que você espera.

Comment: Creio que ordenar por cast(quantidade as integer) DESC resolva seu problema.

Comment: Mateus você é um gênio e ainda abriu minha mente! foi bem simples, revisei a estrutura do meu banco e reparei que era mesmo varchar e agora esta tudo certo!!!!

Comment: Mateus poderia responder a pergunta para eu sinalizar ela como melhor resposta e assim ajudar outras pessoas?